# AS3 air multiple resolutions, assets and layout iphone and ipad app

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I am building an app in AS3/Air and I would like to target both iPhone and iPad resolutions. I understand the different aspect ratios between iPhone and iPad however the app I am building currently has different layout and slightly different content to fit the different screen sizes. I currently have 2 versions of the app already built, one for iPhone the other for iPad. All assets have been created with the target platform in mind but now, I would like to combine the 2 apps into a single one.

I am thinking I will rename each each screen file to iphone_login, ipad_menu, ipad_settings etc and include them all in the same build. Then during startup, check what device the user is on and set iphone_ or ipad_ and also set the resolution at this time too.

I prefer not to have black edges going from iphone resolution to ipad so my questions are:

1. Is my approach a suitable one considering the outcome I would like?
2. How do I determine what device a user is on to show the correct files, assets and resolution?

I understand the app size will increase at least double by adding 2 sets of assets and 2 sets of code files but considering the differences in design layout and content I don't see another solution, apart from keeping 2 apps.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem? iPad and iPhone have different resolution and dpi combination, check them and identify current platform.
Get view you need by class like this:

```
public static const PAGE1:String = "page1";
public static const PAGE2:String = "page2";

private static var PHONE_VIEW_NAME_2_CLASS:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
private static var TABLET_VIEW_NAME_2_CLASS:Dictionary = new Dictionary();

public class ViewProvider 
{
    {
        PHONE_VIEW_NAME_2_CLASS[ViewProvider.PAGE1] = Page1PhoneView;
        PHONE_VIEW_NAME_2_CLASS[ViewProvider.PAGE2] = Page2PhoneView;

        TABLET_VIEW_NAME_2_CLASS[ViewProvider.PAGE1] = Page1TabletView;
        TABLET_VIEW_NAME_2_CLASS[ViewProvider.PAGE2] = Page2TabletView;
    }
    public function ViewProvider()
    {
    }

    public static function isTablet():Boolean {
    ...analyze Capabilities.screenResolutionY, Capabilities.screenResolutionX and Capabilities.screenDPI
    }

    public static function getViewClass(name:String):Class
    {
        return isTablet() ? TABLET_VIEW_NAME_2_CLASS[name] : PHONE_VIEW_NAME_2_CLASS[name];
    }

}
```

And in your program

`navigator.pushView(ViewProvider.getViewClass(ViewProvider.PAGE1))`

All coordinated, paddings and another position numbers, font sizes etc correct with multiplier depending on runtime dpi by simular way...

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the middle of a similar problem.

My solution is to have the images at the best resolution in a file pool, and then downscale them depending on the device when the app starts. You can do this also with non animated vector assets and put them into a bitmapData object.

Another option is to always have the asset pool with files at the maximum resolution needed loaded in the memory, and downscale them at runtime when they are needed. This works well if you will be using some asset in different places at different sizes, for example an icon.

As for the code, you should find a way to separate the code that manages data, the codes that manages the logic, and the code that "paints" the UI. This way you will be able to reuse most of the code in both versions, but only change the code that "paints" the UI. Check the MVC pattern for more info.